# Android Beam - vCard Not Init'ing

Tags: nfc, vcard, android-beam

When I try to send a contact from one nexus 5 to another, Android Beam fails (everything is enabled). Other things such as a pic, a Play App link, etc. work just fine.

When I pull the log, I can see vCard fails to init.  I'm not using any special apps. Just plain stock Android running 4.4.2. Any ideas what's causing this issue?

01-20 14:18:56.187 W/ContactsProvider(16573): Failed to init VCardComposer

01-20 14:18:56.187 E/ContactNfcHandler(30975): IOException creating vcard

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Do you have enough storage available? If so, have you tried to reboot?

Comment: No, memory\storage is not the problem. Something else is going on.